# What causes this div:hover animation not work?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
    background-color:green;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:10%;
    text-indent: 7px;
    border: 4px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div:hover {
    animation-name: animation;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;}
}

@keyframes animation {
    0%{
        border-radius:10%;
        background-color:orange;}
    33%{
        border-radius:22%;
        background-color:#bad455;}
    66%{
        border-radius:35%;
        background-color:purple;}
    99%{
        border-radius:50%;
        background-color:black;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text .</p>
</div>
```

Hello, I'm currently trying to learn animations. And right now it seems like I've did everything right. But when I hover over the div , animation basically doesn't do anything , even though I've did the whole animation correctly. If I try to do this on div without hovering it  , then it works. But as soon as I add :hover to it , it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have one `}` too many, remove it, and it'll work, after the `div:hover`

Comment: Oh god, my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand why people are posting the same answers again and again.

Comment: @Arex Our answers where only 1 sec away from each other, so we basically posted them on the same time.

Comment: @edga9966 I you want to avoid syntax errors in the future - you should consider formatting your code.

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim and when it's a typo error we don't answer .. we flag the question for *typo error*

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` in your css.
Here is the working code:

```css
div {background-color:green;
   height:500px;
   width:500px;
   margin:auto;
   border-radius:10%;
   text-indent: 7px;
   border: 4px solid red;
   box-sizing:border-box;
     display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

 div:hover {
  animation-name: animation;
 animation-duration: 0.5s;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;}
 

    @keyframes animation {
     0%{
      border-radius:10%;
      background-color:orange;}
     33%{
      border-radius:22%;
      background-color:#bad455;}
     66%{
      border-radius:35%;
      background-color:purple;}
     99%{
      border-radius:50%;
      background-color:black;
     }

    }
```

```html
<div><p>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text .</p> </div>
```